# Initially receive FirebaseError: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined. but then works on refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am building an e-commerce website using node.js with the next.js framework for SSR and firebase/firestore as my database.

I have successfully made the website get data and display data from firestore in my view that shows all available products. I now want to be able to click on a product and be taken to an individual product page where it displays extra info + options for the product. I am using the unique SKU number I have assigned products as a reference to get the correct data from firestore.

However, when clicking on the item and being redirected to this page I keep receiving the error that the stringSKU is not a valid third argument. As soon as I refresh the page I get the expected output.

I have used an 'await' in order to get the stringSKU before the promise occurs and logging to console before the promise occurs gives the correct value. Here is my code.

```
export default class Product extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps(context) {
     const obj = await context.query;
     const stringSKU = await obj.SKU

     //Displays the correct string value
     console.log(stringSKU)

    let firebase= await loadFirebase()


    let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {

      //this is where the error occurs
      firebase.firestore().collection('products')
      .where('SKU','==',stringSKU)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) =>{

          let data = []
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {data.push(Object.assign({id: doc.id }, doc.data())) })

          resolve(data)
      })

      .catch(error => { 
         reject([])
      })
    })

     return {products: result}

  }
```

Also, as I am only trying to retrieve one item from firebase I feel that using forEach and putting the item into an array is not the best way of doing this, nor is using the SKU to retrieve the documents.

Any suggestions for how to improve this code by just assigning the returned object to a single variable and using the auto-assigned firestore ID would be great! Sorry I'm a javascript/node.js n00b :)

Comment: You are saying: "I have successfully made the website get data and display data from firestore in my view that shows all available products." if you already have a view that displays all available products from firestore - can't you on your single product page just fetch the document by using the key of the product from the previous page? Also if you already have all products - why don't you cache them locally and display the information for the one selected from cache? Firestore is downloading the whole documents anyway.

Comment: I can't find a way to retrieve the whole document using the firestore assigned ID, so I resorted to using the items SKU which is unique anyway (is on the same level in the database that the relevant data sits), however I receive this error on the initial page load - I will trial the cache technique however